# Robomongo can't connect: Missing expected field

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, robo3t, amazon-rds

I tried to connect to MongoDB in AWS using Robomongo. When I connect, I got this error:

```
Cannot connect to the MongoDB at x.x.x.x:27017

Error:
Missing expected field "mechanism"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this error? I already open the `27017` port to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: First off, mongodb does not run on AWS RDS, so those tags cannot apply to this question.  Second, opening your database to the world is a very bad idea.  Third, can you connect to mongodb with another tool, like mongo shell?

Comment: Yup, you are right. It turns out it was in the instance. Sorry, I am still quite a newbie in AWS and moreover website security.

Never mind, I already able to connect using Robomongo

Answer (score 14):

In Robomongo change in Connection Settings - Authentication - Auth Mechanism from SCRAM-SHA-1 to MONGODB-CR.

Comment: What is difference between  SCRAM-SHA-1 and MONGODB-CR.

Comment: I quote from the developer (http://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/core/security-scram-sha-1):   
MongoDB’s implementation of SCRAM-SHA-1 represents an improvement in security over the previously-used MONGODB-CR, providing:  
- A tunable work factor (iterationCount),  
- Per-user random salts rather than server-wide salts,  
- A cryptographically stronger hash function (SHA-1 rather than MD5),  
- Authentication of the server to the client as well as the client to the server.